# cannot generate notification from broadcastReceiver

Tags: android-intent, android-notifications, android-broadcast

*This is my manifest file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.broadcastlistner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.broadcastlistner.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastlistner.receiver.MyBroadCastListener"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
     <action     android:name="android.intent.com.example.broadcastlistner.receiver.MyBroadCastListener.PHONE_STATE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

   </application>


    </manifest>
```

*similary this is my broadcast Receiver class. and the whole application runs but i donot receive any notifications when the phone is either ringing or any phone state is changing. therefore anyone can help me .the aid will be greatly appreciated*

```
    package com.example.broadcastlistner;

        import android.app.Notification;
        import android.app.NotificationManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
        import android.telephony.*;
        import android.util.Log;

        public class MyBroadCastListener  extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        String phoneNumber = null;
              Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
             if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    phoneNumber = extras
                        .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                    if(phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.trim().length()==0)
                        phoneNumber = "";


                   Log.i(state, "Incomming no");
             createNotification("Incomming      Number:",phoneNumber,context);

             }
             else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
             {
                  System.out.println("call Disconnected");
                 Log.i(state, "offhook");
            createNotification("Phone Disconnected:",phoneNumber,context); 
             }
             else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
             {
                  System.out.println("Phone is idle");
                  Log.i(state, "phone idle");
                 createNotification("Phone Idle:",phoneNumber,context); 
             }
        }

            // check the current state
    }
        public static void createNotification(String subject,String phoneNumber,Context         context)
    {
        // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
        // notification is selected

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Build notification
        // Actions are just fake
        String longText="this is a test message and will be handled after ward";
        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(subject+" "+ "From: " )
                .setContentText(phoneNumber)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                //.setSound(sound)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(longText)) 
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Call", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "More", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "And more", pIntent).build();


        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
    (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check the code intent.putExtra(); It should be before sendBroadCast() or PendingIntent.getBroadCast().
I also have similar problem. And at last I find I do the putExtra() after getBroadCast().So the intent actually contains nothing.